# JQuery: Trying to inject css if on homepage and the the anchor tag HREF contains something

Tags: jquery

The way I set up my site, my homepage ("/") is also an MVC Controller/Action at ("/Dashboard"). I am using tabs for navigation, so Dashboard corresponds to the first tab. If at any point you click Dashboard, my code will make the tab active, as well as any other tab is made active if navigated to.

However, with the homepage it's tricky as my code checks to match the anchor tag's `href` to determine if the tab is active. If I check on "/", all the tabs are made active as that is contained in each `href` (e.g., "/Dashboard", "/Dashboard2", etc.).

This is the (EDIT) entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/(?!^)\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $(".toptab a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ((path == "/") && (path.substring(0, href.length) == "/Dashboard")) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--tabs m-menu__item--active m-menu__item--active-tab');            
        }
        else if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--tabs m-menu__item--active m-menu__item--active-tab');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('m-menu__item  m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--tabs')
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT 1: This is my homepage anchor tag `<a class="m-menu__link" href="/Dashboard">` all other anchors are syntactically the same, the only thing that changes is the name (e.g., "/Dashboard2" would be the page /Dashboard2, etc.).

EDIT 2:The second and third else if/else conditions work to set the tabs active/inactive.

Any suggestions? This code won't fire. If I just use the "/" portion, all the tabs are made active.

EDIT 3:  This is what the HTML looks like on the homepage (the final `else` is applied):

```
<ul class="toptab m-menu__nav  m-menu__nav--submenu-arrow">
    <li class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--tabs">
        <a class="m-menu__link" href="/Dashboard">
            Dashboard
        </a>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add the anchor tag for `home page` as well as for some other pages too. It will clarify your question

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle please?

Comment: @Refilon It won't actually run in JSfiddle. And the actual HTML and CSS are quite lengthy. I am using a purchased theme, and the above code works otherwise to set the tabs active/inactive. It's just on website load it won't work because the anchor tag is for "/Dashboard" and a check for "/" sets all tags active as that is included in each tag (e.g., "/Dashboard2", "/Dashboard3"...).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using this on the first `if` statement:

```
if ((path == '/') && (href == '/Dashboard'))
```